# Django automatically resubmitting the form on refreshing the page

Tags: django, forms

Whenever I fill the form then I click on submit button of the form to store it in the database it stored the data perfectly but when I refresh the page it again submits. So the problem is it is showing the same data multiple times in the database.

**Here is my Django Template code**

```
<h4 class="text-center alert alert-success">Add New Students</h4>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %} 
      {{form.as_p}}
      <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
```

How can I tackle this ?

**Here is my view function**

```
def add_show(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fm = StudentRegistration(request.POST)
        if fm.is_valid():
            nm = fm.cleaned_data['name']
            em = fm.cleaned_data['email']
            pw = fm.cleaned_data['password']
            reg = User(name=nm, email=em, password=pw)
            reg.save()
            fm = StudentRegistration()
    else:
      fm = StudentRegistration()
    stud = User.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'enroll/addandshow.html', {'form': fm, 'stu':stud})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Post method in correct way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In view, Post method should be handled properly. After Post method you should use **redirect** (to same view) instead of **render**.

```
 def add_show(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            fm = StudentRegistration(request.POST)
            if fm.is_valid():
                nm = fm.cleaned_data['name']
                em = fm.cleaned_data['email']
                pw = fm.cleaned_data['password']
                reg = User(name=nm, email=em, password=pw)
                reg.save()
                fm = StudentRegistration()
                return redirect('url_mapped_to_current_view') 
        else:
          fm = StudentRegistration()
        stud = User.objects.all()
    
        return render(request, 'enroll/addandshow.html', {'form': fm, 'stu':stud})
```